# Minesweeper challenge #2

Tags: logical-deduction, probability, minesweeper

Again, I seem to have run into another situation where there doesn't seem to be a definitive set of squares to tap to solve a Minesweeper puzzle.

What squares should I tap to maximize my chances of solving the puzzle, and what is the probability I can solve this puzzle without hitting a single mine?

[image: Screenshot of puzzle]

The above screenshot was taken from the bottom right corner of the whole grid of squares. There are 8 undiscovered mines in the above segment.

---

**Update:** I did some further investigation, and I narrowed the above puzzle down to this:

> [image: Narrowed puzzle]

Which of the above squares is the safest? Is there a definitive solution?

Hint:

> [image: Safe tile uncovered]
>  Here's the safe tile uncovered.

Comment: What difficulty would this game be being played on? i might be able to solve it with that info...

Comment: @BladeWraith Expert, 30x16, 99 mines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a complete solution but should be a good start:

> [image]
>  In each of the colored rectangles there can be 1 mine at most. So I'd go for the bottom right rectangle as it has the most tiles. You should have at least 80% chance of success on the first tap. After that I guess it depends on what is revealed.

Post update:

> From now on you need to guess. There are 6 mines in 12 tiles. Chance of success is exactly 50% no matter where you click. If you don't hit a mine, after that it's straightforward.

Comment: Note that I've now added an update to the question.

Comment: @gparyani I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> There are 21 blocks currently to choose from, and 8 mines, of which 7 are accounted for already and there are only 6 blocks that you have no information on. so picking one of those would offer the highest chance of success. specifically the lower section of 6 as 4 Mines are known to be in the upper section and 3 mines the lower section

However...

> based on the information available to you the 4 in the lower section has 3 blocks to choose from and 1 mine in it, so 2/3 that you'll be safe is the better option based on those values alone.

Post Update:

> With it being expert level... and 5s are very common to see in expert, and there are none on the board, the block below the the lower right hand most block will provide two options for a 5 which means it most likely has a mine under it. which would mean that the block to the left is safe